# What is the most authoritative book/translation on Vignana Bhairava Tantra?

Tags: yoga, tantra, book-recommendation, kashmiri-shaivism

- Which book is the original sanskrit account of Vignana Bhairava Tantra?
- What is the story/events surrounding the time this Yoga method was introduced to the world?
- Which is the best available English translation of the same?

Comment: @TheDestroyer how in the world is this not an opinion based quesiton???

Answer (score 5):

OSHO's discourse on Vigyan Bhairav Tantra is a masterpiece. He has done a detailed analysis on all the 112 meditation techniques of Vigyan Bhairav Tantra.

Here are two volumes of ebook of OSHO's Vigyan Bhairav Tantra:

- [Vigyan Bhairav Tantra - Vol 1](http://www.oshoworld.com/e-books/eng_discourses.asp?pdf_id=148_Vigyan_Bhairav_Tantra_Vol1.pdf&download=Yes)
- [Vigyan Bhairav Tantra - Vol 2](http://www.oshoworld.com/e-books/eng_discourses.asp?pdf_id=149_Vigyan_Bhairav_Tantra_Vol%202.pdf&download=Yes)

> The Book of the Secrets: A New Commentary, The original series of 80
>   discourses were simply called ”Vigyan Bhairav Tantra”. For publication
>   as books they were divided up into 5 volumes, called the ”The Book of
>   the Secrets Volume 1 - 5” (16 discourses each).The books were later
>   published as ”Vigyan Bhairav Tantra Volumes 1 and 2”,(40 discourses
>   each). The two volumes also came with a deck of 112 cards to represent
>   the various meditations.
>
> Talks given from 01/10/72 pm to 01/03/73 pm

Here is the Audio Discourse of it:

http://www.oshoworld.com/discourses/audio_eng.asp?album_id=38

Comment: links broken as of now

Answer (score 2):

One of the best exposition of Vijnana Bhairava tantra in English language is by Sri Jaideva Singh. It is also very famous book on the subject. It is one of the prime texts of Kashmir Shaivism/Shiva absolutism

You can download it [here](https://archive.org/details/VijnanaBhairavaOrDivineConsciousnessJaidevaSingh).

It deals with 100+ methods of meditation which is believed to be directly revealed by Lord Maheshwara.